# What is the best way to initialize an JS Date to local midnight?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I did a lot of research across StackOverflow but didn't seem to find the proper answer for this.

Say I have a date in this format `yyyy-MM-dd` and I'm trying to create a Date object with it. Take 2014-04-04 as an example. When I do `new Date("2014-04-04")`, it will result in:

*Thu Apr 03 2014 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)*

But What I really want is the midnight of that date of the local timezone, something like this:

*Thu Apr 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)*

What is the fastest way to do that in JS without libraries?

Comment: [`date.setHours(0, 0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)

Comment: This is not what the question is asking. `setHours(0,0)` will result in `Thu Apr 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` with the example

Comment: Then use `date.setHours(24, 0)` for the other midnight :-)

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps in the format yyyy-MM-dd are parsed by they built–in parser as UTC (per [ECMA-262](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse)), so for systems set to a negative UTC offset, the local date will be the day before. So you have to start by parsing the string as a local date, at which point you can also set the time to 24:00, or just add one to the day (cases where +1 goes over the end of the month are handled by the constructor so 31 Apr becomes 1 May).

```js
// Parse date in format yyyy-mm-dd as local midnight
// at the end of the day
function parseAsLocalMidnight(s) {
  let [y, m, d] = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(y, m-1, +d + 1);
  // or
  // return new Date(y, m-1, d, 24);
}

console.log(parseAsLocalMidnight('2021-04-17').toString()); // Sun Apr 18 2021 00:00:00 [local offset]
```

Of course if you want midnight at the start of the day, don't add 1. :-)